# Building a website in Rapidweaver that queries a Parse database

Tags: parse-platform

I wrote an iOS app for a client that uses Parse as a backend. My client now wants a website built to display the database contents. It will need to display an image and populate some standard fields.

I'm not a web guy, but I have put together a couple of sites using Rapidweaver. I can't find any examples of people building a site in Rapidweaver that queries a Parse database.

Is this possible?